Stream map().collect() java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaskNode taskNode = new TaskNode();
        ArrayList<TaskNode> taskNodeList = Lists.newArrayList(taskNode);


        List<String> nodeStateList2 = taskNodeList.stream()
                .map(taskNode1 -> getString(taskNode1.getConfig(), ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <K> String getString(final Map<? super K, ?> map, final K key) {
        if (map != null) {
            final Object answer = map.get(key);
            if (answer != null) {
                return answer.toString();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}

@Data
class TaskNode{
    private LinkedHashMap config;
}

I'm unable to compile and on the console it displays:

java.lang.Object Unable to convert to java.util.List<java.lang.String>

I know it's because the TaskNode.config property doesn't declare generics, but I don't understand why. Can you explain in detail the reasons for the occurrence.
I am using Java 8. java -version prints:

java version "1.8.0_381" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_381-b09) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.381-b09, mixed mode)


Sounds to me like using something raw that should be generified. Apparently possibly related: Collecting a raw stream into a typed collection?

I cannot reproduce. Maybe a [mre] without the google and lombok imports, please, since they don’t appear to be central to the problem?? Even when getConfig() returns a raw LinkedHashMap, your code runs on my Java 19. Possibly the rules for generics have been relaxed in later Java versions compared to the version you are using (just a guess).

This may indeed be an issue with your compiler as I experienced this from time to time, e.g. between Java 8 and Java 11 the compiler got smarter when handling generics on call chains and nested generics inferences (like Collectors.toList() would infer it from the arguments to collect()). Which JDK are you using?

@Thomas java -version:
java version "1.8.0_381"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_381-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.381-b09, mixed mode)

Try to go for a newer JDK then, e.g. Java 11. Or try helping the compiler, e.g. via Collectors.<String>toList().

Your LinkedHashMap is using raw types. Don't do that. If you don't care what gets stored in it, then declare it as LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>.

I think that you can get your Java 8 to accept the code with a cast: (Map<String, ?>) taskNode1.getConfig(). I haven’t tried. In other words, that the answer to your question is similar to the answer to the question I linked to in my first comment.
